# Fill List<int> with default values?

Tags: c#, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto-Initializing C# Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104457/auto-initializing-c-lists)

I have a list of integers that has a certain capacity that I would like to automatically fill when declared.

```
List<int> x = new List<int>(10);
```

Is there an easier way to fill this list with 10 ints that have the default value for an int rather than looping through and adding the items?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466946/how-to-initialize-a-listt-to-a-given-size-as-opposed-to-capacity and a few others.

Comment: Yep, my question was a dupe of that first one...

Comment: It seems duplicated, but actually not, for me. *Not all the programmer knows java's array initialization.*

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Well, you can ask LINQ to do the looping for you:

```
List<int> x = Enumerable.Repeat(value, count).ToList();
```

It's unclear whether by "default value" you mean 0 or a custom default value.

You can make this slightly more efficient (in execution time; it's worse in memory) by creating an array:

```
List<int> x = new List<int>(new int[count]);
```

That will do a block copy from the array into the list, which will probably be more efficient than the looping required by `ToList`.

Comment: I was hoping there was some sweet little method call to do this like 'new List<int>(10).Fill()' or something.  Thanks for the quick answers.

Comment: @JonSkeet: is that possible for custom class list?  example: `List<Items> listOfItems` where `public Items {int id; DateTime currentDateTime;}`  Need to have same values for `currentDateTime`.  possible?

Comment: @user1671639: It's not really clear what you're asking for (nor why `Items` would be plural rather than `Item`). Why would it be useful to create a list with lots of "default" entries like this? I suggest you ask a new question with more detail.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I will ask for a new question.  Thanks Jon.

Comment: Hey @JonSkeet, how would you do the above for List<List<int>>? I have asked the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40313729/initialize-a-listlistt-with-default-values)

Answer (score 17):

```
int defaultValue = 0;
return Enumerable.Repeat(defaultValue, 10).ToList();
```

Answer (score 13):

if you have a fixed length list and you want all the elements to have the default value, then maybe you should just use an array:

```
int[] x  = new int[10];
```

Alternatively this may be a good place for a custom extension method:

```
public static void Fill<T>(this ICollection<T> lst, int num)
{
    Fill(lst, default(T), num);
}

public static void Fill<T>(this ICollection<T> lst, T val, int num)
{
    lst.Clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        lst.Add(val);
}
```

and then you can even add a special overload for the List class to fill up to the capacity:

```
public static void Fill<T>(this List<T> lst, T val)
{
    Fill(lst, val, lst.Capacity);
}
public static void Fill<T>(this List<T> lst)
{
    Fill(lst, default(T), lst.Capacity);
}
```

Then you can just say:

```
List<int> x  = new List(10).Fill();
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
List<int> list = new List<int>(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var count = 10;
var list = new List<int>(new int[count]);
```

**ADD**

Here is generic method to get the list with default values:

```
    public static List<T> GetListFilledWithDefaulValues<T>(int count)
    {
        if (count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Count of elements cannot be less than zero", "count");

        return new List<T>(new T[count]);
    }
```