# Initialize a List<List<T>> with default values

Tags: c#

One of the ways of initializing `List<T>` with default values (of that type T) is

`List<int> foo = new List<int>(new int[5]);`

This would create a List with 5 zeroes. How would you do it for `List<List<T>>`?

I know we can do it using for loops or using Enumerate.Repeat (but that creates a deep copy) but would like to know if it can be done like above?

Comment: `new List<T>(new List<T>())` or `new List<T>(new List<T>(default(T)))`?

Comment: `var foo = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => new List<int>());` Replace `5` with however many inner lists you want.

Comment: Your example is calling [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx). This works: `var a = new List<List<int>>(new List<int>[5]);`, but obviously you need to iterate into the 5 elements and instantiate each list. Nothing like this is is any other [constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0cyc8ex(v=vs.110).aspx), meaning no, I don't see a default way to initialize nested lists. Note there are essentially hidden for loops in `Enumerable.Repeat` or `.Select` or equivalent, i.e., you syntactically might hide the loop but it's still there.

Comment: Well default value of List<T> is null. So new List<List<T>>(new List<T>[5]) will make with default values(nulls). if you want to create new Lists you can try new List<List<T>>(new List<T>[] { new T[5].ToList(), new T[5].ToList() })

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [collection initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) to initialize a list with pre-determined values inline.

```
    object a, b, c, d, e;
    var foo = new List<object>()
    {
        a, b, c, d, e
    };
```

If you want to initialize a list with multiple instances of the same object, the List class doesn't give any solutions. You should probably stick to using a loop.

If you're looking for clever hacks, you can try:

```
var foo = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => 42));
var bar = new List<string>(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => "default"));
var far = new List<object>(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => new object()));
```

But don't tell anyone I said that.

Answer (score 0):

Short of creating your own subclass, there is no way to do it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14131034)

Comment: It is the correct answer, just not the one he wants to hear.